# LinAlgError: Singular matrix, solve linear equation python

Tags: python

i want to solve this linear equation in python

```
import numpy as np 

x2=264
x1=266
x3=294
y2=270
y1=240
y3=227

fract=(x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x3-x1)

A = np.matrix([[fract-(y3-y1)*(x3-x1)+(y2-y1)*(x2-x1),((x3-x1)**2)-(x2-x1)**2],[((y2-y1)**2)-(y3-y1)**2,fract+(y3-y1)*(x3-x1)-(y2-y1)*(x2-x1)]])
B = np.matrix([[(fract+(y3-y1)*(x3-x1)-(y2-y1)*(x2-x1))], [y1*fract+(y2-y1)*(x1*y2-y1*x2)+(y3-y1)*(x3*y1-y3*x1)]])

A_inverse = np.linalg.inv(A)

X = A_inverse * B 
print (X)
```

LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Comment: Are you sure a solution exists? As it stands A is singular which means it's not linearly independent and the determinant is 0. Even taking the pseudo-inverse (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) doesn't give the proper solution. Using pinv, we get a result for X but going back to check A*x =? B gives a LHS that isn't even close to the RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained simply by printing `A`:

```
[[ -510   780]
 [  731 -1118]]
```

Both cofactors are `570180`, so the determinant is `0`.

As the error message tells you, the matrix is singular, which means there is no unique solution: either none or infinite, depending on the constants applied.